# How to detect argument character length instead of amount of arguments

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

So I am trying to make it detect how many characters args has. Currently .length just detects how many different arguments are in there, which isn't really what I want. How would I go about making it detect how many characters the remaining arguments have instead? Hope I explained that well.

```js
args = args.slice(3);
let argDescription = args.join(' ');

const maxLength = 10
console.log(`Args Length: ${args.length}`)

if (argDescription.length > maxLength) {
    console.log('Spam Detected!')

}
```

Comment: What is the problem with your code? Can you give concrete examples of what it should detect, but doesn't, or vice versa? Can you make the code a runnable snippet with those problematic examples (use the toolbar in the editor)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you actually already did it by yourself. I don't exactly understand why you checked the length of `args` instead of `argDescription` that already does the work.

For a quick explanation, you have two variables: `args`, which is an array of all elements of the original arguments array from index 3 and beyond, and `argDescription`, which is a string that represents all of those elements connected with a space. using `.length` on an array returns the amount of elements it has, while using `.length` on a string returns how many characters it has.

Assuming you originally wanted to console.log the amount of characters there are in `argDescription`, you can simply replace `args` with `argDescription`.

#### Final Code

```js
args = args.slice(3);
let argDescription = args.join(' ');

const maxLength = 10
// console.log(`Args elements length: ${args.length}`)
console.log(`Args Length: ${argDescription.length}`)

if (argDescription.length > maxLength) {
    console.log('Spam Detected!')

}
```